# Get all tags on a specific branch using GitHub REST API

Tags: github-api

Looking to the [GitHub repository API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/), there is one operation to list all branches of a repository, e.g.:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/branches
```

and also an operation to list all tags of a repository, e.g.:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/tags
```

However, I don't find in such documentation any way of getting all tags *on an specific branch*. Is there any way of doing that, please?

Answer (score 1):

There's no API method that will do this directly, but you could list all tags in the repository via

`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/tags`

and then use the [commit compare API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits) to return a list of commits (in the "commits" part of the response) between the branch base and branch head?