# GitHub API - How to list the latest tag in a branch

Tags: git, rest, github-api

By using GitHub API V3, how to find the latest tag created on a branch ?
I am using java client to call these V3 APIs.

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags API doesn't seem to list either the time created or the branch it was created from.

The objective is to list all the 'Pull Requests' that were created after the last tag was created in 'release' branch. Basically, those PRs that would go into the current release ( next tag to be created).

So since I am using GitHub APIs for this, my approach was to

1. Find the latest tag that was created on release branch
2. Compare the commits between that tag and current develop branch.
3. Filter all the Pull Request merge commits.

Hence, need some help on #1. Any other better ways to achieve this would be helpful too.

Comment: Git tags aren't "created on" or "created from" a branch. They're simply (ideally immutable) pointers to commits. A branch is a mutable pointer to a commit. You can create a tag at the head of `some-branch` today and delete `some-branch` tomorrow; in that case, would you say that the tag was "created from `some-branch`"? What's your actual goal? This sounds like it may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Chris : thanks for your inputs. I have updated the post with my use-case and requirement. Any inputs would be of help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831029/get-all-tags-on-a-specific-branch-using-github-rest-api

Comment: Not exactly. Any solution would help

Answer (score 3):

If i understood your question correctly, you may be able to do this by following the commit that is associated with the creation of the tag. From the commit information we can find the date of the commit. Then, we can find all PRs that were created after the commit date. For example,

1. First we find the tags associated with a repo - `https://api.github.com/repos/giampaolo/psutil/tags`
2. From the json response received for the request (1), we can use the `["commit"]["url"]` field and request the commit level information. In our case, it is- `"url": "https://api.github.com/repos/giampaolo/psutil/commits/fe0799f98e04b980c3f9aee0dd577567eb932e0b"`
3. The json response received for the above request will have the committer information and the corresponding date of the commit.

> ```
> {   "sha": "fe0799f98e04b980c3f9aee0dd577567eb932e0b",   "commit": {
>     "author": {
>       "name": "Giampaolo Rodola",
>       "email": "xxx@gmail.com",
>       "date": "2017-09-01T10:27:38Z"
>     },
>     "committer": {
>       "name": "Giampaolo Rodola",
>       "email": "xxx@gmail.com",
>       "date": "2017-09-01T10:27:38Z"
>     },
>     "message": "pre-release",
>     "tree": {
>       "sha": "00cd23c710c3065cf959a914a74b6062be1e2986",
>       "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/giampaolo/psutil/git/trees/00cd23c710c3065cf959a914a74b6062be1e2986"
>     },
>     "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/giampaolo/psutil/git/commits/fe0799f98e04b980c3f9aee0dd577567eb932e0b",
>     "comment_count": 0
> ```

4. Using the `["commit"]["committer"]["date"]` field you can search all issues that are pull requests i.e. `type:pr`, that has been created after this date. This request should look something like this  `https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:giampaolo/psutil+created:>2017-09-01+type:pr`